# add image to customized button

Tags: html, css

I am using the following CSS to create a custom button

```
.myBlackButton02 {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #6a6f76;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #6a6f76;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -3px 7px 0px #6a6f76;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #61656c), color-stop(1, #292b2e));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #61656c 5%, #292b2e 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #61656c 5%, #292b2e 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #61656c 5%, #292b2e 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #61656c 5%, #292b2e 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #61656c 5%, #292b2e 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#61656c', endColorstr='#292b2e',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#61656c;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #040405;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    padding:9px 23px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #263666;
}
.myBlackButton02:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #292b2e), color-stop(1, #61656c));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #292b2e 5%, #61656c 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #292b2e 5%, #61656c 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #292b2e 5%, #61656c 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #292b2e 5%, #61656c 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #292b2e 5%, #61656c 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#292b2e', endColorstr='#61656c',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#292b2e;
}
.myBlackButton02:active {
    background:transparent;
}
```

and my HTML is:

```
<div id="d1" style="height:46px;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;" class="heading01" >
        <div id="d2" class="style1" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:4.5px;color:#FFF;">Heading</div>
        
        <div align="right" style="padding-top:2.5px;padding-right:10px;">
        
            <button class="myBlackButton02" style="font-size:10pt;outline:none;"> x </button>
            <button class="myBlackButton02" style="font-size:10pt;outline:none;"> x </button>
            
            
            <button class="myBlackButton02" style="font-size:10pt;outline:none;">
                <img src="icons/extensions/right_16.png" style=""/> 
            </button>
</div>
```

and the css for heading01 is

```
.heading01{
    background: rgb(69,72,77); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(69,72,77,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#45484d', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

with those what i am getting is

[image]

but what i want is for all the buttons to be at the same vertical height. i know there is a way to do this but i don't know how. so any help would be appreciated. i even tried doing it by setting the image as a background image but the gradient becomes a solid color, even tried it with a div but it's the same is the image. thanks

Comment: Just an idea. Instead of "x" and arrow image you can use [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the next code to your .myBlackButton02 CSS:

```
vertical-align: middle;
width: 50pt;
height: 30pt;
```

You must define your preferred button width and height according to your image.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing div tag at the end of your html. Also, remove the padding and set a width and height for your buttons. Set vertical-align to middle as previously stated.  [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/58xYG/)

Simplified CSS:

```
.myBlackButton02 {
    /*padding:9px 23px;*/
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css set a `margin-top: x px;` for each and that should make them all level.